# Track campaign analytics in firebase with android platform

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have integrated the firebase dynamic links(with campaign parameters) successfully and everything is working fine and i am getting the parameters at app after install the app from play store through dynamic link and it's also showing the click in dynamic link section at firebase panel.

But the problem is this that i am not able to track the analytics regarding this on firebase dashboard.

Second thing I am not getting that how can i track that which campaign is giving better result for me:
is this can i achieve only using dynamic url or i have to something else

I have read all documentation of firebase but not clear regarding the campaigning working.

Comment: are you able to see the dynamic links related events such as dynamic_link_app_open, dynamic_link_app_update or dynamic_link_first_open in your analytics events console? Make sure that your app is able to handle or receive the dynamic links first and record the analytics data.